# how to delay python function without affect imported .py?

Tags: python

Two .py in one folder:
a.py:

```
def main():
  a=1
  while a<100:
    a++
    print(a)
```

b.py:

```
import a
s=time.time()
e=s
while (e-s)<5:
  a.main()
  time.sleep(3)
  e=time.time()
```

During `time.sleep(3)`,`a.main` will be blocked,sleep 3 seconds.
how to keep `a.main` running when `e=time.time()` delayed?

Comment: `a.afunc` doesn't do anything. It doesn't call the function.

Comment: Does a.afunc() called?

Comment: `sleep` does not block `a.main` at the moment `a.main` runs to completion the you sleep

Answer (score 0):

usually you cant do this with python. you would need the imported .py to be running as a seperate application. python isn't multithreaded so it cant run multiple commands at the same time. if you do time.sleep(5) it will pause the running of the program for 5 seconds. if you wanted the other code to run, during the sleep, that would be considered 2 commands running at the same time as the time.sleep() command hasnt been completed yet. you could try doing complecated stuff to run 2 python applications at the same time but that would be finnicky and difficult.
one way you could for exaple, print out a value every N cycles you could do this is,

```
count = 1
while (e-s)<5:
    count += 1
    a.main()
    if count % 10 == 0:
        e = time.time()
```

this will print the value of count, every 10 cycles.
it checks if 10 is a multiple of count and if it is, it prints the value of count.
you could replace print with time.time() and every Nth cycle it prints time.
change my code however fits best.